# Developing a Custom Printer Driver for Linux/Windows

Tags: windows, linux, serial-port, driver, usbserial

I want to use my designed USB/Serial device as a printer so that the "print" action on my Linux/Windows send the data (which asked to print) to my new printer (my own designed device/printer) connected on USB/Serial port.

Could you please give me the steps to do it? I am not sure where I should start from and how to proceed with this project?

I have an option for either Windows or Linux.

Comment: Does it need the data to be in any special format?

Comment: Windows and Linux have very different print driver models. I'd recommend splitting this into two questions, one for Linux and one for Windows.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, lets assume that I have structured data and I want to print them in some format.